# Pycharm Pro FastAPI default configuration not recognizing environment variables in files besides main.py

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, environment-variables, fastapi

I have a FastAPI python app setup in Pycharm Pro with the default configurations. I've added environment variables to 'Run/Debug Configurations' window. I also have an .env file (which is gitignored) containing the same variables.

Apparently, this .env file is completely ignored by Pycharm when locally testing. Only the variables I've set inside the Run/Debug Configurations window are recognized - and these are only accessible from main.py, the file that runs the FastAPI app.

Accessing environment variables defined this way from main.py works with any of the following:

```
# these all work inside main.py but can't be accessed outside of main.py
os.environ['VAR_HERE']
os.environ.get['VAR_HERE']
os.getenv['VAR_HERE']
```

Why isn't Pycharm recognizing environment variables outside of main.py (in helper modules, etc.) ? How can I get Pycharm to recognize environment variables outside of main.py ?

I'm hosting this app on Heroku. I have an external redis init file which references a Heroku-stored config var with no issues. For some reason, redis is also working correctly locally too. But if I try running the redis init file from Pycharm directly, print statements show environment variables as "None"...

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 0):

For the `.env` file to be activated you have to set the working directory the the directory where the .env file is located. This is usually outside of the module root, where your `app.py` or `main.py` lives; if you don't do this, the working directory is set inside the module itself - and the `.env` file isn't picked up. This is the default behavior when you've just selected run/debug.

Edit your configuration and set the working directory explicitly to the directory containing your `.env` file - this is usually a level up from your module directory.

[image: Example of configuration values for working directory in PyCharm dialog]

Comment: so I have a structure like this:

PycharmProjects > root_app_module containing in a single layer >
-- venv (directory),
-- .env,
-- redis_init.py,
-- main.py, 
-- etc.

and I've set Working directory to root_app_module, which contains .env and main.py, the file with the fastapi app run statement. 

But still getting an error if I try to reference environment variables from any file other than main.py. Should I attempt to go one more directory up? ( hmm the comment doesn't want to render the newlines for the file structure, but basically it's very flat)

Comment: Well - _how_ are you attempting to use the `.env` file? It doesn't do anything magic by default - i.e. a `.env` file doesn't magically appear as environment variables in your application. The usual solution is to use a class that inherits from `BaseSettings` from pydantic that defines the expected values. The `.env` file then overrides these values. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/#reading-a-env-file  The `dotenv` module is required to support this. You can also use dotenv yourself, but Pydantic's BaseSettings work great.

Comment: hmm well according to documentation here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/ you don't need Pydantic BaseSettings unless you're trying to reference an env variable that isn't a string.  Or am I not understanding it correctly? Running main.py, the file with Fastapi app declaration, seems to make all of the (string) env variables in any file inside the project module work. It's just running the non-main.py files on their own that isn't recognizing env vars. I'll give the suggestion with config.py file a try, but my concern is that it won't play nicely with Heroku hosting.

Comment: No, the `.env` support is part of having pydantic installed with dotenv-support and is part of the BaseSettings package: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#dotenv-env-support - The `BaseSettings` module uses environment variables by default, so you can use it with _either_ a `.env`-file or regular environment variables: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/settings/#environment-variable-names